# Xcode Linking - Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, mach-o, build-settings

I try to create an Objective-C Framework with `Relocatable Object File` for Mach-O Type in Xcode Build Settings.

When I build the framework, the `command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code` error appears. 
The error description is `clang: error: invalid argument '-compatibility_version 1' only allowed with '-dynamiclib'`. It will be fine if I change the Mach-O Type with `Dynamic Library`.

Do you guys know how to fix this error with `Relocatable Object File` without change to `Dynamic Library`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer when I change the `Compatibility Version` and `Current Library Version` to an empty text

Comment: Please elaborate how exactly that relates to your original problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove STSecurity framework and keychain access if you are getting Ld failed with nonzero.

Screenshot

[image: 1]